# How can I secure a WCF communication with net.tcp binding

Tags: .net, wcf, security, distributed, net.tcp

How can I secure a WCF communication with net.tcp binding between two C# applications ?
I've run into transport and message security, but is there a solution which I could implement which uses one of those ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733089.aspx).

The client is authenticated and messages are secured using Windows authentication.